# 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'set_value'

Tags: python, python-3.x, appium

I want to set a value in editbox of android app using appium. And I am using python script to automate it. But I am always getting some errors.
My python script is

```
import os
import unittest
import time
from appium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
import uiautomator
import math



        element = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name('android.widget.EditText')
        element.set_value('qwerty')
        element = self.driver.find_element_by_name("Let's get started!")
        element.click()
        time.sleep(5)
```

When ever I am running it, I am always getting an error:

```
AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'set_value'
```

Comment: Your code snippet is not complete.Or may you can try dir(element) to see if it has attribute 'set_value'.

Comment: I've looked at widget EditText and there is no such method you use. For explanation look at my answer.

Answer (score 4):

To type a value into a WebElement, use the Selenium WebDriver method `send_keys`:

```
element = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name('android.widget.EditText')
element.send_keys('qwerty')
```

See the [Selenium Python Bindings documentation](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html?highlight=send_keys#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.send_keys) for more details.

Comment: This seems outdated since trying to insert a character like "@" results in another error: "Cannot construct KeyEvent from non-typeable key".

Also the link you posted no longer works.

Answer (score -1):

It's as simple as the error:
The type element is, has no set_value(str) or setValue(str) method.
Maybe you meant

```
.setText('qwerty')?
```

Because there is no setText method in a EditText widget:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html